# Href + textview + android

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have this code for show product.
how to make each textview a clickable link to open a siteweb ?

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

 Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private EditText et_number;
    private Button btnSet;

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

 url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http:xxxx/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

 JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


 products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);


     Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

     Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

     on seleting single product
     launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
             getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();


        }
    });

}

 Response from Edit Product Activity

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
         if result code 100 is received 
         means user edited/deleted product
         reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


     Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();


                setBadge(AllProductsActivity.this,
                        Integer.parseInt("6"));
                Toast.makeText(AllProductsActivity.this, "please see badge on your application in launcher", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
         Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

         Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
             Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                 products found
                 Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                 looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                     Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                     creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                     adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                     adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                     adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                 no products found
                 Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                 Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
         dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
         updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                 updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Not clear to me what the question is

Comment: You could use Linkfy or Html.fromHtml() or if you can take the url easily maybe just a onclicklistener

Comment: can you tell me where i can put the Html.fromHtml() in my code because i try but  always i failed @Nanoc

Comment: textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlString)); its pretty straighforward

Comment: where i can put this code in my application??? . can you read my code and help me where i can put this code@Nanoc